# Replace word in text file with word in a list do some operations and start over again

Tags: python

I am a beginner in programming and I could need some help. I have a list with 30 000 different values and I would like to replace the word "cat" in a text file with the first value in the list to some operations where I use the text file and then start over again with the next value in the list.
The text file look something like this:

```
    <QVariantList name="Filters">
        <QVariantMap>
            <QVariantMap name="Filter">
                <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]FactorImage" value=""/>
                <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]OffsetImage" value=""/>
                <bool name="enabled" value="true"/>
                <double name="factor" value="1"/>
                <QString name="name" value="DSNU"/>
                <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
```

and the list I have looks like this:

```
[[-2271.0000000000005],
 [-2318.0],
 [-2377.0],
 [-2425.0],
 [-2406.0],
 [-2360.9999999999995],
 [-2287.0],
 [-2208.0],
 [-2173.0],
 [-2147.0],
 [-2181.0],
 [-2199.0],
 [-2183.0],
 [-2117.0]]
```

I started a code and I am able to replace the word with another word like this:

```
filename = "testtext.txt"

with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
    text = f.read()
    text = re.sub('cat', 'dog', text)
    f.seek(0)
    f.write(text)
    text = f.truncate()
```

But I get stuck when I want to iterate over the list:

```
filename = "testtext.txt"
df_list = df.values.tolist()
global filename
for i in range(len(df_list)):
    with open(filename, 'r+') as f:
        text = f.read()
        text = re.sub('cat', df_list[i], text)
        f.seek(0)
        f.write(text)
        text = f.truncate()
        # here I want to do some operations where I use the text file
        print: ("now working on file" + df_list[i])
```

Any help would be appreciated :)

Comment: 1) Why are you reading and rewriting the file after each substitution, 2) why are you using re.sub when you're not using a regualar expression and just want to perform 1 replacement.  You can use text = text.replace('cat', df_list[i], 1) to replace the first occurrence each time.  3) line `global filename` is unwarranted.

Answer (score 0):

IIUC, the following code should accomplish your task.

```
# Assuming this is your list
lst = [[-2271.0000000000005],
 [-2318.0],
 [-2377.0],
 [-2425.0],
 [-2406.0],
 [-2360.9999999999995],
 [-2287.0],
 [-2208.0],
 [-2173.0],
 [-2147.0],
 [-2181.0],
 [-2199.0],
 [-2183.0],
 [-2117.0]]

# Get file contents
filename = "testtext.txt"
with open(filename, 'r') as f:
    text = f.read()
    
# Perform replacements
for value in lst:
    # looping through values in list
    if 'cat' in text:
        # Perform one replacement of 'cat' with value[0]
        text = text.replace('cat', str(value[0]), 1)  # Use value[0] since value is a list
        # Feedback to user of replacement value
        print(f'Replaced cat with value {value[0]}')
    else:
        break  # 'cat' not found
            
# Write new contents back to file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
```

**Example**

File: testtext.txt

```
<QVariantList name="Filters">
    <QVariantMap>
        <QVariantMap name="Filter">
            <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]FactorImage" value=""/>
            <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]OffsetImage" value=""/>
            <bool name="enabled" value="true"/>
            <double name="factor" value="1"/>
            <QString name="name" value="DSNU"/>
            <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
            <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
            <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
            <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
            <int name="offset" value="cat"/>
```

File testtext.txt after running above code

```
<QVariantList name="Filters">
    <QVariantMap>
        <QVariantMap name="Filter">
            <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]FactorImage" value=""/>
            <QUrl name="[OPENFILE]OffsetImage" value=""/>
            <bool name="enabled" value="true"/>
            <double name="factor" value="1"/>
            <QString name="name" value="DSNU"/>
            <int name="offset" value="-2271.0000000000005"/>
            <int name="offset" value="-2318.0"/>
            <int name="offset" value="-2377.0"/>
            <int name="offset" value="-2425.0"/>
            <int name="offset" value="-2406.0"/>
```

Comment: with this code I can replace the word "cat" with the first value in the list (-2271.0000000000005) one time. The thing is I want to do this for every value in the list but after the first iteration the word "cat" is not in the file anymore so I want to replace whatever word is kept on the place of "cat" actually..any ideas?

Comment: @sananvalinte--I forgot one parameter in replace (check updated answer).  I had it in my comment but forgot to add it to the actual code.  Now if you have 'cat' appearing twice, the first 'cat' is replaced with -2271.0000000000005 and the second with [-2318.0.  Is this what you had in mind?

Comment: when I run the updated code it still just replace "cat" once. My goal is to replace whatever is written at the "cat" place with the first word in the list..then I want to do something which uses the text file (still in the for loop) and then I want to start over again with the next value in the list and so on

Comment: maybe instead of cat say: "offset" value="%d" ?

Comment: @sananvalinte--I added an example of what the code does when 'cat' appears multiple times in file testtxt.txt.  How is this different from what you want?

Comment: ah if I dont use the last snippet of the code it works!
`
# Write new contents back to file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
`

Comment: @sananvalinte--what works?  Didn't you want the file to change?  Also, does the example I added illustrate what you're trying to do?

Comment: when I removed: # Write new contents back to file
with open(filename, 'w') as f:
    f.write(text)
 it worked the way I wanted. I didnt want to add multiple lines in the text file just replace "cat" one time do some operations and then go on relacing it with the next...sorry I am bad at explaining..

Comment: @sananvalinte--okay, as long as it works for you.